# boxshadow for input-group lg?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my search box:

```
 <div class="search-box col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-4">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <input type="search" width="100%" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" id="q" name="q">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
       <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
       </div>..........
```

and I'm trying to change the color of the box glow [box-shadow]

I altered

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(89,133,39,.6);box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(89,133,39,.6)}
```

(the rgb was originally 82,168,236) in my docs.min.css

but it doesn't seem to have any affect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not exactly sure where you are having the issue, or if you are referring to a specificity issue, if so use !important while testing to see if that is the case. Otherwise look at -webkit-appearance: none; https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good on the snippet. I think it's better if you work on a non-minified css.

Also consider bootstrap might be overriding your css rule, so try adding  important at the end of the line.

```
input {
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(89,133,39,.6);box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(89,133,39,.6) !important;
}
```

---

```css
input {
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(89,133,39,.6);box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(89,133,39,.6);
}
```

```html
 <div class="search-box col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-4">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <input type="search" width="100%" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-lg" id="q" name="q">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="button">Search</button>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```